# Use of pthreads mutexes and semaphores in Java native library code

Tags: java, multithreading, java-native-interface, pthreads, native

In a Java application, a class has some native methods which may be called
from different threads. The implementation of the native methods needs
to access shared static data (visible only in the native code), hence some synchronization mechanisms are required (semaphores, mutexes and/or condition variables).

It is safe to use the POSIX utilities shipped by the platform (`sem_*`, `pthreads_mutex_*`, `pthread_cond_*`), even though the threads are created by the Java side (non-native)?

Comment: Why not to synchronize the native method invocations in Java code?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Because the logic of the application may imply (like in my case) that the methods should be callable in a non-synchronized order. If a native method does `static native resource access` + `other work`, only the part of the method accessing the static native resources should be synchronized.

Comment: You could also consider using the JNI `MonitorEnter` and `MonitorExit` functions to synchronise on Java objects; for static data these could be classes. This could increase the portability.

Comment: I am talking about static resources in the native sense ([static meaning in C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword/static)): internal resources of the C library implementing the native methods, not accessible outside the library.